# Soap API Account Creation via SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, trailhead

Hi I am Trying to create the Account From SOAP API but getting below error :

SOAP Project:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:SessionHeader>
         <urn:sessionId>REMOVED</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:create>

         <urn:sObjects xsi:type = "urn1:Account" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2010/XMLSchema-inst">
         <Name>Bluebeards Grog House</Name>
         <Description>It is better than Blackbeards.</Description>

         </urn:sObjects>
      </urn:create>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Error :

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>sf:INVALID_TYPE</faultcode>
         <faultstring>INVALID_TYPE: Must send a concrete entity type.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <sf:InvalidSObjectFault xsi:type="sf:InvalidSObjectFault">
               <sf:exceptionCode>INVALID_TYPE</sf:exceptionCode>
               <sf:exceptionMessage>Must send a concrete entity type.</sf:exceptionMessage>
               <sf:row>-1</sf:row>
               <sf:column>-1</sf:column>
            </sf:InvalidSObjectFault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Two quick tips: use the `{}` tool in the editor to format your code blocks (Stack Exchange otherwise will not show most XML/HTML tags), and please _don't_ post valid session Ids for your orgs, which could grant anyone access. I've removed this.

Comment: Sure :: I will be careful from next time.